# ¿Cuál es la diferencia exacta entre CONST y FINAL en Dart?

Tags: dart

He buscado en internet pero no me ha quedado muy claro la diferencia entre las palabras reservadas **const** y **final** en Dart.

Comment: Podes agregar que fue lo que entendiste? asi no te contestan lo mismo que no te quedo claro, de vuelta...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La diferencia esencial es que una variable **const** no puede ser algo a calcular a la hora de la ejecución, es decir, deben ser inicializadas con un valor constante, un ejemplo sería la fecha actual, no puedes hacer:

```
const date = new DateTime.now();
```

Se podría utilizar, por ejemplo, para algo como:

```
const dias_de_la_semana = 7;
```

Por otro lado, una **final**, aunque inmutable (es decir, su valor no puede cambiar), sí que se puede inicializar con algo en **run-time**:

```
final date = new DateTime.now();
```

Answer (score 5):

Aparte de lo dicho en la respuesta aceptada que en resumen es que los ***final*** se pueden instanciar en tiempo de ejecucion y los ***const*** NO

Existen otra diferencias importantes:

A nivel de objetos (todo es un objeto) hay diferencias significativas entre ***const*** y ***final***, cuando se le asigna ***final*** a una variable, ese objeto no es 100% inmutable, en cambio cuando se asigna ***const*** éste si es inmutable, por ejemplo:

```
final valor = [1,2,3,4];
print(valor); //imprime el array [1,2,3,4] , valor asignado inicialmente.
valor.add(5); //Hacemos uso del método para agregar valor al array
print(valor); //imprime el array [1,2,3,4,5], Observamos que el valor inicial del array
```

se alteró, es decir, mutó.

En cambio si hacemos lo propio con ***const***:

```
const valor = [1,2,3,4];
print(valor);
valor.add(5); // Error Unhandled exception:  Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list)
print(valor)
```

;

La asignación de ***const*** a un objeto si hace que los valores sean inmutables

De hecho si intentamos que la lista asignada como ***final*** no sea mutable, deberíamos hacer ésto:

```
final valor = const [1,2,3,4];
por lo cual lo siguiente no sería válido:
final valor1 = const [1,2,3,4];
  valor1.add(4); //Error
  print(valor1);
```

Ahora si intentamos algo similar pero al contrario:

```
const valor = final [1,2,3,4] //Es imposible de hacer
```

En cambio, si hacemos ésto:

```
const valor = const [1,2,3,4]; // la asignación es válida.
```

Otra cosa, cuando se asigne const a una variable de instancia, es necesario utilizarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
static const miVariableDeInstancia
```

No pueden ser ***const*** solamente.

esta respuesta es de José L. Martínez lo pueden encontrar en los comentarios de este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y211yYfvtoY&list=PLl_hIu4u7P64F8DRNSoXifvNxVa5pyHAN&index=5

Comment: Buena respuesta @erick-lesser-diaz ¡Gracias!